# Variable doesn't recognize previous conversion?

Tags: c#

I'm doing a console app for calculating BMI using arbitrary formulas for practice. The problem is with switch (index), Visual Studio keeps telling me that switch can't use double, even though I've already converted index to int. Simply using Convert.ToInt32(index) doesn't work either. What am I missing here?

```
        bool loop = true;
        int suly;
        double magassag;
        double index;
        string valasz;

        while (loop)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Add meg a sulyodat");
            suly = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Add meg a magassagodat");
            magassag = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            magassag = magassag / 100;


            index = suly / Math.Pow(magassag, 2);
            index = Math.Round(index, 2);



            Console.WriteLine(index + " a testtomeg indexed");
            index = Convert.ToInt32(index);

            switch (index)
            {
                case (0-5):
                    Console.WriteLine("asd1");
                    break;
                case (6-10):
                    Console.WriteLine("asd");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("asd3");
                    break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Újra? igen/nem");
            valasz = Console.ReadLine();
            if (valasz == "igen")
                loop = true;
            else loop = false;
```

Comment: just cast index to int switch((int) index)

Comment: `case(6-10):` is `case -4:`, probably not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use double in a switch. Index is still a double

`index = Convert.ToInt32(index);`

This converts the double value of index to an int. You then assign it to index (which is a double), which does an implicit conversion back to double.

`int foo = Convert.ToInt32(index)` would work

or even `switch(Convert.ToInt32(index))`

---

Just some notes: 
1) You should declare your variables when you need them. For example `suly` exists in the [scope](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpVariableScopes.aspx) of main, when it only need to be in the scope of the while loop.

2) Your loop variable is doing what the `break` keyword already does

3) Convert.ToInt32 already provides rounding (that's one of the things that makes it different from a cast ( `(int)index` ).

4) things like `magassag = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); magassag = magassag / 100;` could easily be done in one statment, and probably would be a bit clearer.

5) case (0-5) means case(-5), case (6-10) is -4. You want use if statements `if( foo >= 0 || foo <= 5)` or use [switch statement fallthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx)

Comment: That should probably be an `int` instead of a `double` ;)

Comment: Ah, i was under the impression that it also converts the variable itself. Well, there's a lot to learn.

Thanks guys :)

Comment: @Chris Ha! Oh dear, that was the one thing not to get wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It's always a good idea to just debug your program. 
Visual Studio helps you a lot in these cases.
Set a breakpoint after your calculation on the index variable.

In the watches window you can check the type.

[image]

Anyway as a solution I agree with Praveen Paulose

```
switch(Convert.ToInt32(index))
```

Comment: No  it is easier to ask on SO. Obviously :-)

Answer (score 0):

The data type for index is double. That is why you get this error.

Try passing an int as shown below

```
switch(Convert.ToInt32(index))
```

Answer (score -1):

The `index` is declared as `double index;`. Change that into `int index;`:

```
    bool loop = true;
    int suly;
    double magassag;
    int index;  // not double 
    string valasz;
```

Otherwise the assignment will promote the `int` value produced by `Convert.ToInt32()` back into a `double` again, thus produce the error you see. The other solution is to throw out the `index` at all and just do the conversion where you need it:

```
    switch( Convert.ToInt32(index))
```